# How do i properly get list view title and display it via toast?

Tags: java, android

I am working on a note application which has a list view and adapter. I have a context menu implementation on each list view item which pops up delete option. When the delete option is clicked, an alert dialog appears.  I have been unable to concatenate the title of each selected list view item and display it in a toast. How do i properly obtain the title of each list view title and cast it to a toast? My logic for now gives me a null pointer exception.

My Main Activity

```
private Note mLoadedNote = null;
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.edit:
                    break;
                case R.id.delete:
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setTitle("delete note")
                            .setMessage("really delete the note?")
                    .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if(mLoadedNote != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  mLoadedNote.getTitle() + " is deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  "can not delete the note '" + mLoadedNote.getTitle() + "'", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                    })
                        .setNegativeButton("NO", null); //do nothing on clicking NO button :P
                    alertDialog.show();
            }
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Note Serializable

```
public class Note implements Serializable {
    private long mDateTime; //creation time of the note
    private String mTitle; //title of the note
    private String mContent; //content of the note

    public Note(long dateInMillis, String title, String content) {
        mDateTime = dateInMillis;
        mTitle = title;
        mContent = content;
    }

    public void setDateTime(long dateTime) {
        mDateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        mContent = content;
    }

    public long getDateTime() {
        return mDateTime;
    }

    public String getDateTimeFormatted(Context context) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
                , context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale);
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        return formatter.format(new Date(mDateTime));
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return mContent;
    }
}
```

Note Adapter Class

```
public class NoteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Note> {

    public static final int WRAP_CONTENT_LENGTH = 50;
    public NoteAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Note> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.view_note_item, null);
        }

        Note note = getItem(position);

        if(note != null) {
            TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_note_title);
            TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_note_date);
            TextView content = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_note_content_preview);

            title.setText(note.getTitle());
            date.setText(note.getDateTimeFormatted(getContext()));

            //correctly show preview of the content (not more than 50 char or more than one line!)
            int toWrap = WRAP_CONTENT_LENGTH;
            int lineBreakIndex = note.getContent().indexOf('\n');
            //not an elegant series of if statements...needs to be cleaned up!
            if(note.getContent().length() > WRAP_CONTENT_LENGTH || lineBreakIndex < WRAP_CONTENT_LENGTH) {
                if(lineBreakIndex < WRAP_CONTENT_LENGTH) {
                    toWrap = lineBreakIndex;
                }
                if(toWrap > 0) {
                    content.setText(note.getContent().substring(0, toWrap) + "...");
                } else {
                    content.setText(note.getContent());
                }
            } else { //if less than 50 chars...leave it as is :P
                content.setText(note.getContent());
            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post more code? In the main activity mLoadedNote = null and never assigned so the value is always null.

Comment: You have to create a click listener in the view holder of your item to show the AlertDialog. In that case get the button in the adapter throw the convertView View class and create the listener right there. After that just add the AlertDialog code to handle the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You done all right, it is just missing get the selected object `Note` of the list.
To do so, try:

```
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
Note mLoadedNote = (Note) getListAdapter().getItem(info.position);
mLoadedNote.getTitle()
```

Without that code, your object `mLoadedNote` will always be `null`, and the `Toast` will never show up.

Comment: My solution does not involve knowing you `ArrayAdapter`. You already try what i said?

Comment: You may face a problem with `getListAdapter()`, what you should have to implement, ou substituir by `mList.getAdapter()`

Comment: had an issue with "position". where do i pass that parameter?

Comment: You use position to get the object `Note` using `(Note) getListAdapter().getItem(info.position)`

Comment: i finally got everything working now. thanks. you just saved me

Comment: My pleasure =) don't forget to mark this your question as closed and this answer as the right one